# Vb.net count down from now to predefined timespan?

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, timer, countdown, timespan

I would like to be able to (on button click) start a countdown (in minute intervals, that also updates every minute) from the current time to a timespan that already exists. How can I do this?

I read somewhere there are a few different timers, I need a solution that I can use in windows phone 7 as well as in a windows forms application.

I'm aware there are a lot of existing questions, I just can't seem to find one that does this exact thing - if someone could point me in the right direction even?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the number of minutes and seconds between two timespans, then you can subtract a number of seconds or minutes from this new timespan each second to determine a new timespan, this new timespan will reduce each time the subtraction occurs. Once this new timespan reduces to 0, you know the time is up or the countdown has completed.